# 3D CSS and jQuery Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gallery

I want to know if there's a way to show more than 3 images on this script. I already tried, but I couldn't do it.

Link: http://tympanus.net/Development/3DGallery/

If it's impossible, is there any other plugin in this same style?

Thanks.

Comment: lets share the code with us what you tried?

Comment: @KheemaPandey This is the original code (http://tympanus.net/Development/3DGallery/js/jquery.gallery.js), I tried to change some 'if' where it sayed 3 to more items. But I realized that the plugin classify the images on Left, Center and Right. So I assume that we can't have more than 3 images.

Comment: in your HTML code you can put many of images. As shows in this link. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/02/06/3d-gallery-with-css3-and-jquery/

Comment: I know that, but when I say 3 items I mean show more than 3 items at once. On the page, only 3 images are show, if I want to see the others, I must wait the slideshow or use navigation, what I want is that 5 items appear at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't with this plugin (well, obviously you can with vast amounts of changes, as in recoding it from scratch). And the reason is it basically spins through a left, center and right screen, so you can't add more "states". You will even see leftCSS, rightCSS and currentCSS, which applies to the 3 different states

About options to this, there are a lot of options, most of them paid, but you can check [3D Flow](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/plugins/3dflow.php), which is free and has a lot of different view options